# How to append multiple "'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset"?

Tags: tensorflow, append

I have the below part code in my image classification task. For this task i have to train the model on images in a folder and test the model and predict the accuracy

```
    import tensorflow
    import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing

    data1 = preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("folder",label_mode="categorical",seed=0, image_size=(100,120))

    data2 = preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("folder",label_mode="categorical",seed=0, image_size=(100,120))

    type(data1)
    type(data2)
```

after running this code the result will be stored in the data1 and data2

the type of data1 and data2 is **class tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset**

I want to append data2 to data1 so that i can use the resultant data to train the model.

I tried concatenation earlier

`
data1.concatenate(data2)

`
which is failing at the testing and throws the error **categorical_crossentropy target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible**

I also tried **np.append()** which fails during the training and throws the following error

```
    ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type BatchDataset)
```

But i have to use append to link the data
for example
data1

```
    [(array([[[[165., 166., 170.],
         [165., 166., 170.],
         [165., 166., 170.],
         [158., 157., 155.],
         [158., 157., 155.],
         [157., 156., 154.]],
```

data2

```
     [(array([[[[161., 165., 168.],
         [161., 165., 168.],
         [161., 165., 168.],
         [157., 160., 149.],
         [157., 160., 149.],
         [157., 160., 149.]],
```

appended data should be

```
    [(array([[[[165., 166., 170.],
         [165., 166., 170.],
         [165., 166., 170.],
         [158., 157., 155.],
         [158., 157., 155.],
         [157., 156., 154.]]
         [161., 165., 168.],
         [161., 165., 168.],
         [161., 165., 168.],
         [157., 160., 149.],
         [157., 160., 149.],
         [157., 160., 149.]]
```

I followed this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934511/how-to-concatenate-tensorflow-python-data-ops-dataset-ops-batchdataset](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) for concatenation

Comment: data1.concatenate(data2) is right. The error is for some other reason.

Comment: But concatenation is completely different from append ? How does the concatenate replaces append for tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset?

Comment: there is no append functionality for datasets. Try list(data1.concatenate(data2)) to check the output of it.

Comment: This list(data1.concatenate(data2)) is typecasting the original data type tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset to <class 'list'> and throwing the error while training the model. Error message is :
in _check_data_cardinality raise  ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 28, 28, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32,32, 8, 8
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Comment: list is ONLY to inspect the dataset and not pass to your code. check the list to see the values in it, you will see its concatenated as you expected.

Comment: Thanks @V.M  I can see the list of concatenated dataset

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing

data1 = preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("/content/",label_mode="categorical",seed=0, image_size=(100,120))
output:Found 809 files belonging to 4 classes.


data2 = preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("/content/Pistachio_Image_Dataset",label_mode="categorical",seed=0, image_size=(100,120))
output:Found 2148 files belonging to 3 classes.


combined_dataset = data1.concatenate(data2)
```

The code works fine and does not produce any error.Thank You.